# Eigenvectors and Kronecker product

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, kronecker-product

Let us define
$$
v:=v_A\otimes v_B\quad (*)
$$
where $v_A$ is a fixed vector in $\mathbb{R}^{d_A}$, $v_B$ is *any* vector in $\mathbb{R}^{d_B}$ and $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product. To rule out trivial cases assume $d_A,d_B>1$.

**My question**: Suppose that $v$, defined as in $(*)$, is an eigenvector of the symmetric matrix $C\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$, with $d:=d_Ad_B$, for *all* $v_B\in\mathbb{R}^{d_B}$. Is it true that $C$ has the form
$$
C=A\otimes I_{d_B},
$$
where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{d_A\times d_A}$ and $I_{d_B}$ denotes the identity matrix of dimension $d_B$?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
C=\pmatrix{I&0\\0&D},
$$
where the identity $I$ and an arbitrary symmetric $D$ have the same dimension greater than one.
For $v_A=[1,0]^T$ and any nonzero $v_B$ (of the same dimension as $I$ and $D$), $v=v_A\otimes v_B$ is an eigenvector of $C$. The matrix $C$ does not need to have a Kronecker product form since $D$ is arbitrary symmetric.

Comment: While I see the idea behind it [see also the comments in my post], I don't see why this proves that the statement is wrong. Can you provide a specific counter-example?

Comment: I agree with Dominik.

Comment: @Dominik Better? (At least for the *current version* of the statement.)

Comment: Yes, what a surprisingly simple counterexample. Thanks.

Comment: @Algebraic Pavel: Thank you for the counterexample! I have only one more question. If, in your example, I replace the identity block of $C$ by $\lambda I$, $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, $\lambda\neq 0$, then I have that $v$ is an eigenvector of $C$ associated with eigenvalue $\lambda$. What about the case $\lambda=0$? In this case the counterexample does not work, since $C$ is of the form $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\otimes D$. Do you have a counterexample also for the 0-eigenvalue case?

Comment: @Jacquard This is a different problem, since you've written in your first post that the second matrix in the Kronecker product is supposed to be the identity. It is not clear which assumptions you want to make now and it might be the best if you post another question with the exact setting of this new problem.

Comment: @Dominik: You are right. I posted a question for the new problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411104/a-question-about-matrix-kernels-and-kronecker-products

Answer (score 2):

This is in general false. Consider $v_A = v_B = (1, 1)^t$ and $C = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 2 & 1 & 4 & 3 \\ 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\ 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. Then $v_A \otimes v_B = (1, 1, 1, 1)^t$ and $C (v_A \otimes v_B) = 10 (v_A \otimes v_B)$, but clearly $C$ is not of the form $A \otimes I_2$.

In general, a single eigenvector doesn't say much about the structure of a matrix. I suppose a version of this statement might be true if there exists a whole eigenbasis of the form $u_i \otimes v_j$ with suitable vectors $u_i, v_j$.

Comment: I assume that $v_B$ is *any* vector in $\mathbb{R}^{d_B}$. In your example, if I choose $v_B=[0, 1]^\top$, then $v=v_A\otimes v_B$ is no more an eigenvector of $C$.

Comment: I see, then you should change the wording of your question to "assume that $v_A \otimes v_B$ is an eigenvector for *all* $v_b \in \mathbb{R}^{d_B}$". I suspect that the statement still remains false, because this only yields $d_B$ linearly independent eigenvectors, while $A$ is a $d_A \times d_A$ matrix. But I don't have a counterexample at the moment.