# A question about matrix kernels and Kronecker products

Tags: matrices, kronecker-product

Let us define
$$
v:=v_A\otimes v_B\quad (*)
$$
where $v_A$ is a fixed vector in $\mathbb{R}^{d_A}$, $v_B$ is *any* vector in $\mathbb{R}^{d_B}$ and $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product. To rule out trivial cases assume $d_A,d_B>1$.

**My question**: Suppose that $v$, defined as in $(*)$, belongs to the kernel of the symmetric matrix $C\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$, with $d:=d_Ad_B$, for *all* $v_B\in\mathbb{R}^{d_B}$. Namely, $Cv=C (v_A\otimes v_B)=0$, for all $v_B\in\mathbb{R}^{d_B}$ and for fixed $v_A\in\mathbb{R}^{d_A}$. Is it true that $C$ has the form
$$
C=A\otimes B,
$$
where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{d_A\times d_A}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{d_B\times d_B}$?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider $v_A=(1,0,0)^T,\ v_B\in\mathbb R^2$ and
$$
C=\pmatrix{
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&1}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the counterexample. If $v_A$ and $v_B$ have the same dimension, i.e. $d_A=d_B$, is the answer still no?

Comment: @Jacquard The answer is still no if $d_A=d_B\ge3$. E.g. suppose $d_A=d_B=3$ and $v_A=(1,0,0)^T$. Take a random real symmetric $C$ whose first three rows/columns are zero.  It's almost always *not* a Kronecker product of two $3\times3$ matrices because its nonzero $3\times3$ sub-blocks are not scalar multiples of each other.

Comment: A last question: in case $d_A=d_B=2$, then is the answer positive?

Comment: @Jacquard (Presumably $v_A\ne0$.) Yes. If $d_A=d_B=2$, by a change of basis (via an invertible matrix $P$ on $\mathbb R^2$ and $P\otimes P$ on $\mathbb R^4$), we may assume that $v_A=(1,0)^T$. So, the condition that $C(v_A\otimes v_B)=0$ for every $v_B$ means that the first two columns of $C$ are zero. As $C$ is symmetric, its first two rows are zero too. Therefore, $C$ is a Kronecker product of $A=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&1}$ and some $2\times2$ matrix $B$.